# Остановить .animate числа. JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animate

Есть задача сделать уменьшение скидки по времени при  открытии модального окна. При закрытии модального окна скидка должна останавливаться и запускаться с того же момента с которого и была остановлена (закрыто модальное окно).

```
$( "#gok" ).click(function() {
  var numb_start = $(".promo-lwo").text();
  $( {numberValue: numb_start} ).animate({numberValue: 1}, {
    // Скорость анимации, где 500 = 0,5 одной секунды, то есть 500 миллисекунд  
    duration: 12500,
    easing: "linear", 
    step: function(val) {
      // Блок, где необходимо сделать анимацию 
      $(".promo-lwo").html(Math.ceil(val));
    }
  });
});

/** Stop animation when button is clicked
    задаем функцию при нажатии на элемент с классом stop */
$( "#stop" ).click(function() {
  // останавливаем выполняемую анимацию
  $({numberValue}).stop([jumpToEnd]);
});
```

Проблема состоит в том что я не знаю, как его остановить. Если останавливать значения селектора, то там все понятно. А здесь не могу разобраться. Тыкал, подстанавливал - не выходит.
Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а как сделать, что бы счетчик не уходил в -. Отсчет завершался на 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать setInterval() вместо использования animate. Например:

```js
var timerId;
var counter = function() {
  var numb_start = +$("#number").text();
  if (numb_start > 0) {
    $("#number").html(numb_start - 1);
  } else {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    $("#number").html("отсчёт окончен");
  }
}

$( "#start" ).click(function() {
  if (+$("#number").text() > 0) {
    timerId = setInterval(counter, 500);
  } else {
    $("#number").html("отсчёт окончен");
  }
});

$( "#stop" ).click(function() {
  // останавливаем выполняемую анимацию
  if (timerId != undefined) clearInterval(timerId);
});
```

```css
button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#number {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">Начать/продолжить отсчёт</button>
<button id="stop">Пауза</button>
<div id="number">100</div>
```

Дополнительное условие в функции counter позволяет останавливать счётчик, чтобы он не уходил в минус.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а как сделать, что бы счетчик не уходил в -. Отсчет завершался на 1

Comment: Ответ отредактирован в соответствии с новым вопросом.